# Wordpress Плагин галереи с возможностью вывода списка галерей и количеством фото

Tags: wordpress, gallery, wp-plugin

Препробовал топовые бесплатные плагины галерей, но не где нет возможности вывода списка галерей(альбомов) (по типу вывода категорий товаров в WooCommerce)

Идея в том что бы вывести на страницу все альбомы (с обложкой одной из картинок внутри и количеством картинок в альбоме). И по переходу уже открыть галерею картинок.

Пример страницы

`альбом 1(обложка альбома) (30 фото)
альбом 2(обложка альбома) (15 фото)
альбом 3(обложка альбома) (10 фото)

и т.д`

Прошу подсказать плагин который может реализовывать такой функционал

Comment: А такое руководство не смотрели? http://enviragallery.com/how-to-add-multiple-galleries-in-wordpress-posts-and-pages/

Comment: Смотрел, либо я слепой, либо там нет упоминания о подобном функционале.

Comment: вопрос не вполне понятен. что нужно - 30+15+10 фото на одной странице? Или все-таки речь о перечне галерей, как тут: http://7818-presscdn-0-76.pagely.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/post-gallery-multiplegalleries.jpg

Comment: Задумка по типу отображение категорий товаров только отображать альбому... уже не суть... я не смотрел аддоны энвиры, там есть такая функциональность  album add on